# Bluetooth send/receive text between windows 7 PC and mobile in c#

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming, bluetooth

i want to automatically find devices around my PC and sent a text message to the new devices (first visited devices) and after their response according to their answer to my message i will sent a file to them.

**My Goal**

i have 3 mobile program and want to sent a message to every mobile around my PC.

> Please Select 1,2 or 3 ....

and want to get response into my program (problem area!)

and after response i will sent the program that user needs to him.

i can sent files, and can find new devices, but i dont know how can chat with mobile and PC

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

use this article may be usefull [Using serial port and At Command for query Cell phone its for me](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/583315/Using-SerialPort-and-AT-Commands-for-Querying-Cell)

Comment: hi mojtaba - sadly i couldn't find my answer in the link -  still have problem ...